# How to resolved Flash Builder 4.7 cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flash, apache-flex

I know this question already asked by many persons but that blogs unable to resolve my problem so I am posting this issue to find a solution.

I'm running Flash Builder 4.7, with Flex 4.6.0, when I am trying to debug my web project I receive an error as below :

C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_26_0_0_131.dll Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player. You might need to install the debugger version of the Flash Player or reinstall Flash Builder. Do you want to try to debug with the current version?

Latest version of flash player i.e Adobe Flash Player 26 ActiveX,NPAPI,PPAPI already installed in my system.

I also tried to uninstall the existing version of flash player and installed the latest version of flash player but that is also not resolved my problem, also tried to change the web browser to Internet Explorer but in that case also I am getting same type of issue as

C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\Flash32_26_0_0_131.ocx Flash Builder cannot locate the required debugger version of Adobe Flash Player. You might need to install the debugger version of the Flash Player or reinstall Flash Builder. Do you want to try to debug with the current version?

So if anybody have idea or knowledge how to resolve this issue please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: *Latest version of flash player...* did you install **debugger** version of FP? You can get the relevant one here: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Comment: Are you able to run your web project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your application in a browser you need to get DEBUGGER version of the flash player for your browser here and install it. If you are using Chrome you need the IE version:
https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

If you are running your project as a standalone swf (not in a browser) you need to download the "project content debugger" from the URL above, rename it to "FlashPlayerDebugger.exe" and copy it over to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\player\win\26.0\FlashPlayerDebugger.exe (26.0 refers to the flash player version you have downloaded). You might need to restart the Flash Builder afterwards

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 does not support flash player content debugging in windows 10.Fire fox and Chrome browsers however allow for the content debugging in windows 10.

To setup fire fox and chrome for content debugging with Adobe Flash Builder, here are the steps.

1) **Setup Flash Builder to use Firefox or Chrome** : In  Adobe flash builder go to Window-> Preferences->General->Web Browser-> {choose your web browser}.

Note: If Firefox or Chrome is not listed there then click on 'New' and on the following modal, Provide the browser name and then for the 'Location' browse to the exe file of          your browser. Click 'Ok' to save and now your browser should be showing on the Web browser list.

2)**Install Flash debugger for Fire fox or Chrome:**

a)  Go to  https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html
    b) For fire fox, Download and install Download the Flash Player content debugger for Firefox - NPAPI 
    c)  For Chrome, Download and install  Download the Flash Player content debugger for Opera and Chromium based applications – PPAPI

3) Testing: Do a build from Adobe Flash builder side and then launch the debugger. The application should instantly connect to the browser's (Forefox or Chrome) debugger.